# ProbabilityDistributionQ

Tags: probability-or-statistics, pattern-matching, distributions

I have had a look through the documentation and I cannot find a `ProbabilityDistributionQ` function.

**How can I return `True` if the argument is a probability distributions and `False` otherwise?**

Comment: check ``Names["Statistics`*`*DistributionQ"]``

Comment: I don't understand how that helps?

Comment: Joe, for example, ``Statistics`Library`ContinuousUnivariateDistributionQ[
 UniformDistribution[{1, 10}]]``  gives `True`, ``Statistics`Library`ContinuousUnivariateDistributionQ[
 BinomialDistribution[n, p]]`` gives `False`, ``Statistics`Library`DiscreteUnivariateDistributionQ[
 BinomialDistribution[n, p]]``gives `True` etc.

Comment: Ah yes right you are that is exactly what I wanted, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[pdQ]
pdQ = Or[Statistics`Library`MultivariateDistributionQ @ #, 
  Statistics`Library`UnivariateDistributionQ @ #] &;
```

Examples:

```
pdQ /@ {BinomialDistribution[n, p], 
  UniformDistribution[], 
  BinormalDistribution[ρ], 
  ProbabilityDistribution[(Sqrt[2]/π) (1/(1 + x^4)), {x, -∞, ∞}], 
  ProbabilityDistribution[16^(2 x + 1)/(Sinh[16] (2 x + 1)!),  {x, 0, ∞, 1}], 
  BinormalDistribution[a, b, c],
  BinomialDistribution[-5, -1], 
  blah}
```

> {True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False}